# knitr generates HTML figure in LaTeX Markdown

Tags: knitr, pandoc

I have an Rmd file and want to convert it into a PDF with knitr-pandoc-latex. Here's a small example that works as intended:

````
---
title: "Minimal Working Example"
author: Author Psaroudakis
date: "August 27th 2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r boxplot, dev='pdf'}
boxplot(mtcars$disp ~ mtcars$cyl)
```
````

that is knitted to:

````
---
title: "Minimal Working Example"
author: Author Psaroudakis
date: "August 27th 2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```r
boxplot(mtcars$disp ~ mtcars$cyl)
```
![plot of chunk boxplot](figure/boxplot-1.pdf)
````

which can be easily turned into a PDF with pandoc. But if I want to resize the plot with `out.width`, knitr turns it into HTML code, but I want to create a PDF, not a HTML page!

````
…    
```{r boxplot, dev='pdf', out.width='50%'}
boxplot(mtcars$disp ~ mtcars$cyl)
```
````

is rendered to:

````
---
title: "Minimal Working Example"
author: Author Psaroudakis
date: "August 27th 2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```r
boxplot(mtcars$disp ~ mtcars$cyl)
```
<embed src="figure/boxplot-1.pdf" title="plot of chunk boxplot" alt="plot of chunk boxplot" width="50%" type="application/pdf" />
````

Does anybody have a solution for this? I've tried `opts_knit$set(out.format="latex");` but it didn't make any difference. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem.  When I create your test document, and run

```
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")
```

(or click on Knit in RStudio), I get the figure at the requested width.  Perhaps your unstated method of converting to PDF is the problem?

Comment: Hi, yes that is exactly right: When I do it with RMarkdown, it works fine, but when I run knitr by hand the above thing happens. My question aimed at doing it the manual way because it surely has to be possible to use knitr without rmarkdown.

Comment: Of course it is.  Just use the options that `rmarkdown` uses when it converts the Markdown to PDF.